# How can i return response json with custom methods?

Tags: php, json, laravel, orm

I have custom function in Hotel Model

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\HotelImage', 'hotel_id', 'id');
}
public function translate(){
    $hotel =  $this->translates->where('lang',app()->getLocale())->first();
    return $hotel ? $hotel : $this;
}
```

in my api controller i return  response()->json($hotels);

```
1. $hotels =  Hotel::with('images')->where(function($query) use($q){
            foreach($q as $price){
                $query->orWhereBetween( 'price', explode(',',$price) );
            }
        })->get();

2. $hotels =  Hotel::with('translate')->where(function($query) use($q){
            foreach($q as $price){
                $query->orWhereBetween( 'price', explode(',',$price) );
            }
        })->get();
```

1 - is working
output 
`id:2,
images:[{id: 3, name: "1505464164_5.jpg", size: 270617, hotel_id: 2}]
name:"test2"
phone:"556464"
place:"Baku, Azerbaijan"`

2 - is not working output 
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()`

Comment: share your $hotels outputs on 1 and 2

Comment: what is `$this->translates`? or should that be `$this->translate`?

Comment: have you tried  return $hotel ? $hotel : $this->get();

Comment: public function translates(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Translate', 'hotel_id', 'id');
    }

Comment: $hotel ? $hotel : $this->get() is fails